# Getting value from dropdown list

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the selected value from a dropdown list.
The list has name 'select_employee', when I press the button with name 'save' I hope to get the value. I'm using a POST to to get the value.

I get the error 'Undefined index: select_employee'.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Enter Certified Course Details</h2>

    <?php
    // start of connect db
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "TrainingDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //end of connect db
    ?>

    <form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <?php
    // Drop down list employee
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Select Employee<br>";
        echo "<select name='select_employee' id='select_employee'>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['sname'] . " </option>";
          }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        echo "save<br>";
        $employee=$_POST['select_employee']; // error here
        echo "Selected Employee" . $employee . "<br>";
    }
    ?>

    <form Employee="/employee_page.php" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="save">Save</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your button is in a different `<form>` to the one where the select box is. So you are not posting anything other than the button to the PHP. The browser only sends inputs from the form where the button is pressed

Comment: Thank you, putting them in one form fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different form so make sure to use only one form.